# Odoo16 - python - how to call action_set_supplier() on vendor list in reordering rules

Tags: python, odoo-16

I'm trying to perform a scheduled action in Odoo v16, which will assign the first vendor from the list in the product to each reordering rules - you can manually click it as in the screenshot.
For this purpose, I created an automated action for testing as in the second screenshot, but it does not work as expected. When I run the script on a record that already has a vendor assigned - nothing happens, on a record without a vendor - an error about going beyond the scope of the list. Can anyone suggest how to do it correctly? Or maybe there is another way to achieve this other than a python script?

```
record.supplier_id.action_set_supplier()
```

It is called on Minimum Inventory Rule (stock.warehouse.orderpoint)

[image]

It seems that supplier_id[0] refers to the already set vendor, and not to the one from the list of vendors visible after clicking the icon at the top of the action_stock_replenishment_info() screen - but I haven't been able to figure out how to refer to this list. I think my way is correct, but I'm missing something.